Is there a way in the gradle build system to prevent all permissions of library dependencies from getting merged into application's manifest?
Recently, Google Play Billing library added Network related permissions, which are not really required for the billing functionality. See Google Play Billing Library 6.0 introduces the INTERNET permission. Can it be avoided? for details.
My question is, can we preemptively prevent such scenarios, by informing the build system to never merge permissions from libraries?
There are ways to prevent a specific permission from getting merged using something like this:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove" />

But this requires manually doing this for each permission, which becomes complicated when different product flavors are involved. It would be great if the merging of permissions could be entirely disabled. And disabling only permission merging, while letting other manifest merges for other attributes.
